# div scrollbar doesn't work when contenteditable is true

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to build something like a Google Docs page, but the scroll bar doesn't work when i put some text on my contenteditable div.

I just want to add some text and be able to scroll with scroll bar.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #EEE;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #contentBox {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: #EEE;
            width: auto;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        #textBox {
            width: 60%;
            min-height: 982px;
            border: 1px #C9C9C9 solid;
            padding: 12px;
            margin-left: 20%;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            outline-style: none;
            white-space: pre-line;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contentBox">
        <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to either give `#contentBox` a height, or use `body`'s scrollbar (remove `body {overflow: hidden;}`).

Comment: You have `Overflow:hidden` in the body remove it.!

Comment: You can check the **[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/P6EEW/)**, in this demo i have added `height:700px;` to the Contentbox and in **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P6EEW/1/)** there is no height also i removed `overflow:hidden` in the body

Comment: It's works. But now I have two scroll bars and one doesn't nothing.

Comment: Have a look here(http://jsfiddle.net/VfWjQ/) to see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit - second try

Ok, this can be arranged. I've just fixed my [first FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7t4YY/3/) for you, since it was losing the white background when it got overflowed with text.

And I also made an [second FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7t4YY/4/) because you said that it must be an "outside scroll" and I'm trying to figure out what is that.

---

> Original answer

What I can recommend you is to understand how overflow works before trying to implement it.

This property depends on the parent's height, and the parent's height can depend on it's grandfather's height, and so on, so your fix might be far away. Because of that, sometimes that property can get harder to debug the more nested your div is.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="title">Must be outside scroll</h1>

<div id="contentBox">
    <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
    height: 100%;
}
#title {
    text-align: center;
}
#contentBox {
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border: 1px #C9C9C9 solid;
}
#textBox {
    width: calc(100% - 24px);
    height: calc(100% - 24px);
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline-style: none;
    white-space: pre-line;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[old FIDLEE](http://jsfiddle.net/7t4YY/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but the result isn't what I really want. But I think it's a good start.

Comment: @AlexandreVicenzi If you want me to try it again, explain what is wrong with my example and I'll try to enhance it for you

Comment: @AlexandreVicenzi I gave a shot at what might be wrong. Give both fiddles a look and remember to test them by typing a lot of text on them.

Comment: Well, If you could create a Document on Google Drive, you will see where I want the scroll bar. It's not on the body, and not on textBox, it's on contentBox. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

remove body `overflow: hidden;`
and `#contentBox` add `overflow-y: hidden;`

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EEE;

   }
#contentBox {
    padding-top: 20px;

    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#textBox {
    width: 60%;
    min-height: 982px;
    border: 1px #C9C9C9 solid;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline-style: none;
    white-space: pre-line;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Here is your code (http://jsfiddle.net/3RE96/1/), it's not what I want to do, have a look.

Comment: I want to have a scroll only in the div, because I have other stuffs in header and footer, like Google Docs. Only the page has scroll.

Comment: scrolled to the div, and one for the page?

Comment: define `height: px;` and `overflow-y: auto;` also `width: px;` in `#contentBox`